# Magento2: How to redirect minicart on checkout cart page?

Tags: magento2, cart, mini-cart

How can I redirect on checkout cart page once I click on Minicart instead of toggle.

[image]

Comment: specify your requirement in detail.

Comment: Is there any solution?

Answer (score 2):

This functionality is already available in Magento 2.
Please set to "No" on 
**Admin-> Stores-> Configuration-> Sales-> Checkout-> Shopping Cart Sidebar-> Display Shopping Cart Sidebar.**

Answer (score 2):

**You can follow below path in admin and set "Display Shopping Cart Sidebar" : "No"**

> Admin >> Stores >> Settings >> Configuration >> Sales >> Checkout >>
>   Shopping Cart Sidebar >> Display Shopping Cart Sidebar: No

Let me know if any issue.

Hope it help!

Answer (score 1):

**on Magento ver. 2.3.4, that option is placed in:**

Admin -> Stores -> Configuration -> Sales -> Checkout -> Mini Cart (tab) -> Display Mini Cart : No

It is related to that function - getIsNeedToDisplaySideBar(), part of that file
module-checkout\view\frontend\templates\cart\minicart.phtml

And your minicart should redirect to -> getShoppingCartUrl()

Hope it helps for people with newer versions.